# Check focus or blur on load

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to check focus or blur from first moment (on load). How do i make it check directly.

HTML

```
<div id=console></div>
```

JS

```
var window_focus;
var conL = $('#console');

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).focus(function () {
        window_focus = true;
        conL.html('Focus');
    })
    .blur(function () {
        window_focus = false;
        conL.html('Blur');
    });
});

console.log(window_focus);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tmx9tmxx/

So on load now `window_focus` is "undefined". I want to make it check directly true or false.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [`:focus`](http://api.jquery.com/focus-selector/) selector for initial check:

```
window_focus = $(window).is(':focus');
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/tmx9tmxx/1/

Comment: this output once `false` in console.log after that it doenst return true or false anymore.

Comment: *after that it doenst return true or false anymore*. What do you mean? You need to add one more `console.log` into event handlers if you want to output `window_focus` on focus/blur.

Comment: Yes like this, but how do i get the value in the `console.log(window_focus);` outside the functions. I want to check it like if (!window_focus) { do this }